# How to let the two line in one line?

Tags: html, css, wechat

I am writing a little-program, and there is a problem I do not understand:

[image]

Look at this, I want the two line text in one line, and the “取消” in the right of "请输入您要查询的文本", they are parallel.

How to do with it?

My code is here, in `search.wxml`:

```
<view class="search">
<view class="section">
    <input placeholder="请输入您要查询的文本" auto-focus/>
    <navigator class="navigator" url="../../index">取消</navigator>
</view>
</view>
```

The `search.wxss`:

```
.search .section {
    height: 90rpx;
    background-color: #eac627;
}
```

My project navigation is the picture show:

[image]

I think I should make a fuss about `search.wxss`, but do not know how to do with that.

Comment: Did you try `white-space: nowrap;` ? Also, it may be the result of your box not having enough horizontal-length , try `width : ...px` , see which length can help you to fit the text.

Comment: use `display: inline-block` for both of your elements i.e. for `input` as well as for `navigator` tag.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay, yeah, it works! but how to make the “取消” button constraint right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to vivekkupadhyay's usful comment, I use wxss selector to get that:

```
#input-word {
  display:inline-block;
}

#cancel-button {
  display:inline-block;
  width:120rpx;
  float:right;
}
```

Thanks again!